# What does this entry shown before a user was made moderator mean?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, moderation-history

On *Drupal Answers* we have two new moderators. Looking at the history shown for the moderator activity of one of them, I have noticed the following entry.

[image: screenshot]

It is for something happened before the user was made moderator; the link takes to an answer of his that he deleted. The post was not flagged from any user. (At least, the page showing the list of all the post flags doesn't show anything.)

[image: screenshot]

What does "deletes flag votes" mean, if there isn't any flag?

Comment: Do notations with drop shadows count as freehand?

Comment: Uhmmm... Does the fact the picture has my fingerprint count? `;)` Skitch removed the freehand tool; all I can do is highlighting things I see in the screenshot. `:|`